# iPad 3 remote test devices

Tags: ipad, testing, remote-access

I have developed an iOS 5 app for iPhone but Apple complains about some non-functional parts on iPad 3. Everything works fine in simulator, so I need to test on a real iPad 3 device. I have looked through different online remote device providers but they all offer only iPad 2 devices.

Is there any provider which might offer an iPad 3? I remember that there is one service offering a bunch of Apple products but I cannot recall it's name nor address.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try [Browser Stack](http://www.browserstack.com)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but Browser Stack uses emulators (not real devices).